# pouchDB is it possible to sync one doc at a time?

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I am using pouchDB for offline mode.
The reasoning for syncing one doc at a time is that the internet connection can be interrupted an i'd like to avoid loss of documents.
Is it possible to sync one doc at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your replications options to use batch_size = 1 and batches_limit = 1 so that each time a document is synced it would send a change event.

It does a good job of syncing on it's own and will go through completely if you leave it alone.  We've found that it recovers very well on bad internet connections and attempting to throttle down the sync on your own with low batch limits can cause unintended consequences.